# Adapt image to container size

Tags: html, image, css

I have a webpage where I display a lot of images in a thumbview, so I have a defined size for all the thumbs:

[image]

Then, the images loaded in that container can be higher or wider, so I want it to be displayed correctly. For example: if the image is higher then should be displayed center:

[image]

Then, if the image is wider, it should be:

[image]

Currently images are filling the whole container, so some of them are not displaying as intended, some are getting extended and others are too wide. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: @AbhishekPandey which code? I simply load dinamically images inside the img elements.

Comment: Have you tried with css or js? and one more question is there any fix resolution for wide and and high type of image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will help

**`flex-box` solution**

```css
div {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div><span><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=28&txt=150%C3%97300&w=150&h=300"></span></div>
<div><span><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=28&txt=550%C3%97200&w=550&h=200"></span></div>
```

**`display:inline-block` Solution**

```css
div {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
}
div:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div><span><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=28&txt=150%C3%97300&w=150&h=300"></span></div>
<div><span><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=28&txt=550%C3%97200&w=550&h=200"></span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you can set the images as background, in CSS you can use:

```
background-size: contain;
```

this simple rule will take care of everything.